# JAVA_HOME is not working for WSO2 product in Cent OS 7

Tags: java, centos, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a CentOS virtual machine. I am trying to install wso2 server in the VM. My `.bash_profile` folder is

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/
export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

But when I start the server it returns,

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
 CARBON cannot execute /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102//bin/java
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be an issue with the JAVA_HOME that u have specified

it should be

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/Contents/Home

and you dont need to export it from the path

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

adding above to your .bash_profile will be enough

Answer (score 0):

The good way set those variables in CentOS is to use `.bashrc` as this is the file which is read by bash on login.